# iscroll - does not work in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I want to set up iscroll in a jsfiddle, but it does not work. What is missing?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssu1o2er/)

JS

```
var myScroll;

 function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { mouseWheel: true });
  }

  document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault();     }, false);
```

Comment: The `onload` event can only be used on the document(body) itself, frames, images, and scripts. In other words, it can be attached to only body and/or each external resource. The div is not an external resource and it's loaded as part of the body, so the `onload` event doesn't apply there.

Comment: see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ssu1o2er/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function IScroll wasn't initialized properly. Onload doesn't work on random divs. Only body and images for example have this: [onload event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q79b7462/)

```js
var myScroll;

$( document ).ready(function() { 
 myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { mouseWheel: true });
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
 -ms-touch-action: none;
}

body,ul,li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

body {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: ubuntu, helvetica, arial;
 overflow: hidden; /* this is important to prevent the whole page to bounce */
}

#header {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 45px;
 line-height: 45px;
 background: #CD235C;
 padding: 0;
 color: #eee;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#footer {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 48px;
 background: #444;
 padding: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #444;
}

#wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 45px;
 bottom: 48px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#scroller {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
 -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
 -o-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
 -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
 -o-text-size-adjust: none;
 text-size-adjust: none;
}

#scroller ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}

#scroller li {
 padding: 0 10px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/build/iscroll.js"></script>
<div>
<div id="header">iScroll</div>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="scroller">
  <ul>
   <li>Pretty row 1</li>
   <li>Pretty row 2</li>
   <li>Pretty row 3</li>
   <li>Pretty row 4</li>
   <li>Pretty row 5</li>
   <li>Pretty row 6</li>
   <li>Pretty row 7</li>
   <li>Pretty row 8</li>
   <li>Pretty row 9</li>
   <li>Pretty row 10</li>
   <li>Pretty row 11</li>
   <li>Pretty row 12</li>
   <li>Pretty row 13</li>
   <li>Pretty row 14</li>
   <li>Pretty row 15</li>
   <li>Pretty row 16</li>
   <li>Pretty row 17</li>
   <li>Pretty row 18</li>
   <li>Pretty row 19</li>
   <li>Pretty row 20</li>
   <li>Pretty row 21</li>
   <li>Pretty row 22</li>
   <li>Pretty row 23</li>
   <li>Pretty row 24</li>
   <li>Pretty row 25</li>
   <li>Pretty row 26</li>
   <li>Pretty row 27</li>
   <li>Pretty row 28</li>
   <li>Pretty row 29</li>
   <li>Pretty row 30</li>
   <li>Pretty row 31</li>
   <li>Pretty row 32</li>
   <li>Pretty row 33</li>
   <li>Pretty row 34</li>
   <li>Pretty row 35</li>
   <li>Pretty row 36</li>
   <li>Pretty row 37</li>
   <li>Pretty row 38</li>
   <li>Pretty row 39</li>
   <li>Pretty row 40</li>
   <li>Pretty row 41</li>
   <li>Pretty row 42</li>
   <li>Pretty row 43</li>
   <li>Pretty row 44</li>
   <li>Pretty row 45</li>
   <li>Pretty row 46</li>
   <li>Pretty row 47</li>
   <li>Pretty row 48</li>
   <li>Pretty row 49</li>
   <li>Pretty row 50</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>


</div>
```